# Array of dynamic string: allocation in external function

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, malloc

I need your help.

I have a static array of N elements. I need to insert, **with a function**, dynamically allocated strings.

Here's my code, which has a problem:

<< warning: passing argument 1 of 'insert' from incompatible pointer type.
   Expected 'char ***' but argument is of type 'char* (*)[N]' >>

Thanks for your help!

```
/* MAIN */
int main()
{
    char* array[N];
    int i=0;

    while (...)
    {
        i++;
        insert(&array, i);
    }
    ...
    free(array);
    return 0;
}

/* FUNCTION */
void insert(char*** arrayPTR, int i)
{
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);

    (*arrayPTR)[i]=malloc( strlen(string) * sizeof(char) );

    strcpy(*arrayPTR[i], string);
}
```

Comment: They are a lot of errors and misunderstanding of memory here, the free is pointless the way you use it for example, not talking about the general structure of your code. Do you understand what you are trying to do with your memory ?

Comment: you don't understand how pointer work, i advice you to go reread a pointer tutorial

Comment: `(*arrayPTR)[i]=malloc( strlen(string) * sizeof(char) );` : `strlen()` is the number of character of your string. So malloc does not contain any space for the null character ``\0`` at the end of the string. Try ``(*arrayPTR)[i]=malloc(( strlen(string)+1) * sizeof(char) );``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Your two main problems are:

1. You're adding an extra layer of indirection when passing your array to your function, which you don't need, and is actually causing you problems.
2. While you need to `free()` the individual array elements, you need not - and should not - `free()` the array itself, because you didn't dynamically allocate it.

Here's what it ought to look closer to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 5
#define MAX_BUFFER 100

void insert(char** arrayPTR, int i);

int main()
{
    char* array[N];

    /*  Populate arrays  */

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
        insert(array, i);
    }

    /*  Print and free them  */

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
        printf("String %zu: %s\n", i + 1, array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void insert(char** arrayPTR, int i)
{
    /*  Prompt for and get input  */

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    char str[MAX_BUFFER];
    fgets(str, MAX_BUFFER, stdin);

    /*  Remove trailing newline, if present  */

    const size_t sl = strlen(str);
    if ( str[sl - 1] == '\n' ) {
        str[sl - 1] = 0;
    }

    /*  Allocate memory and copy  */

    if ( !(arrayPTR[i] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1)) ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(arrayPTR[i], str);
}
```

with output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./dp
Enter the string: these
Enter the string: are
Enter the string: some
Enter the string: simple
Enter the string: words
String 1: these
String 2: are
String 3: some
String 4: simple
String 5: words
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Answer (score 0):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10

void insert(char *arrayPTR[N], int index);

int main(void){
    char *array[N] = { NULL };
    int i, n;

    for(i = 0; i<N; ++i){
        insert(array, i);
        if(*array[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }
    n = i;
    for(i=0; i < n; ++i){
        puts(array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void insert(char *arrayPTR[N], int i){
    int ch, count = 0;
    char *string = malloc(1);

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    while(EOF!=(ch=getchar()) && ch != '\n'){
        string = realloc(string, count + 2);//Size expansion
        string[count++] = ch;
    }
    string[count] = '\0';

    arrayPTR[i] = string;
}
```